# Desktop Header visible in mobile view in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, caching

The desktop header is visible above the mobile header in mobile view in thw wordpress website?

[image]

I use Super page cache for cloudflare plugin for page caching and Litespeed cache plugin for optimizing css and java files. I have disabled all caching functions on the litespeed cache plugin though.

THe problem disappears after I clear all cache on the website. But reappears after some time.